# How can I get the size of a file in x86 assembly Linux

Tags: linux, file, assembly

I would like to get the size of a file I have opened using only assembly language. I am looking for a simple solution since I only need the size to allocate enough buffer space to manipulate the files contents. Basically, I have already opened the file and have the filehadle/descriptor. I Just need to get the size. I've seen several examples but some are hard to follow and assume a very proficient level of Assembly/Linux. I am pretty good but not awesome. This is what I have done so far

```
_start: 

movl     %esp, %ebp     
movl     $5, %eax       
movl     8(%ebp), %ebx      
movl     $0102, %ecx        
movl     $0644, %edx        
int  $0x80          
test     %eax, %eax     
js   fileerror_     
movl     %eax, InputFileHandle      #Stored file handle here
```